# Codeigniter : how to pass hidden parameters in the url and make them available for parsing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I have an url like this :

> www.domain.com/catalog/category_name/category_id/product_name/product_id

example :

> www.domain.com/catalog/notebook/93/4_cpu_quad_core/56

and want it to turn into :

> www.domain.com/catalog/category_name/product_name/

example :

> www.domain.com/catalog/notebook/4_cpu_quad_core

The two ID parameters have to be passed to the application and parsed with PHP as I need it to get the correct category and product.

I have tried several ways using .`htaccess` and `route.php` config but no success !!

Can someone explain in simple manner how to pass these parameters to the web server while making these hidden in the url ?

I was just wondering if it is possible to pass hidden parameters in the url and make them available in the backend application (i.e. java or php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! i wrote a function in the file system/core/uri.php

```
function assing_segment($num,$value)
{
    $this->segments[$num]   =   $value;
    return $this->segments[$n];
}
```

And call to this function either in the view or controller

```
$this->uri->assing_segment(5,$myvalue);
```

This will reassign segment 5 with my value

Comment: Hi Raheel .. I think your idea is very good !! The only problem is that I have a lot of <a href> tags .. and dont know what is the best way to call $this->uri->assing_segment without overloading the system .. should i use jquery to pass these parameter to the server thru ajax before redirecting to the href url ? btw . .really nice solution i would use in my next develpoment ..

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain in simple manner how to pass these parameters to the web server while making these hidden in the url ?

There is no way to "hide" parts of the request. You can remove them, but then your application won't see them at all. For example, you can make all your URLs appear to be like `www.domain.com/catalog/category_name/product_name/`, but your php script isn't going to see anything about any IDs, since they're gone.

Comment: I would like to make my URL a bit more SEO friendly and to achieve this it would be better to remove the UID from the url path .. right ? but in this case i won't be able to get the correct product in the database as i don't think is a good idea to select data by providing the string name .. mmm ..starting to think that there is no solution ..